# Nontrivial map from manifold to real projective space

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

I am doing now old topology quals from Maryland University, and there is a following problem:

If $M$ is compact smooth connected m-manifold, show that there exists non null-homotopic continuous map from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}P^n$, assuming that $m=n$ and $n$ is odd.

How to solve this problem? Also, why odd $n$ is easier? There is an information that this is also true for even $n$.

Comment: Can  $M$ be assumed to be orientable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, suppose $M$ is not orientable.  Then $H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is nontrivial, and so there is a map $f:M\to K(\mathbb{Z}/2,1)=\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ which induces a nonzero map on $H^1(-;\mathbb{Z}/2)$.  Since $M$ is $n$-dimensional, $f$ is homotopic to a map $g:M\to\mathbb{R}P^n$ by cellular approximation.  This map $g$ is nonzero on $H^1(-;\mathbb{Z}/2)$, and in particular is not nullhomotopic.

Now suppose $M$ is orientable.  Collapsing the exterior of an open ball in $M$ to a point gives a map $f:M\to S^n$, which induces an isomorphism on $H^n(-;\mathbb{Z})$ (assuming $n>0$; for $n=0$ the result is not true).  Composing $f$ with the quotient map $p:S^n\to\mathbb{R}P^n$, we get a map $pf:M\to \mathbb{R}P^n$.

There are now two ways we can show $pf$ is not nullhomotopic, one of which requires you to assume $n$ is odd.  First, if $n$ is odd, we get this by a simple calculation on cohomology.  When $n$ is odd $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is orientable and $p$ induces multiplication by $2$ on $H^n(-;\mathbb{Z})$.  It follows that $pf$ induces multiplication by $2$ on $H^n(-;\mathbb{Z})$ and thus is not nullhomotopic.

Alternatively, we can note that since $p$ is a covering map, any nullhomotopy of $pf$ would lift to a homotopy from $f$ to a map whose image is contained in a single fiber of $p$.  Since $M$ is connected, the latter map must actually be constant, so this gives a nullhomotopy of $f$.  But $f$ is nontrivial on $H^n(-;\mathbb{Z})$ and so is not nullhomotopic, so $pf$ cannot be nullhomotopic either.

Comment: Why does the map $f:M \to S^n$ induce an isomorphism on $H^n(-;\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: Because $M$ is orientable, its fundamental class in $H_n$ maps to the fundamental class of $S^n$ under $f$ (assuming we choose our orientations so that $f$ is orientation-preserving on the ball we used to define $f$).  Dualizing, we get that $f$ is an isomorphism on $H^n$ as well.

Comment: Wow, I really enjoy the answer for non-orientable case! Also, one of the assumptions (which I forgot to write) was that $\pi_1(m)$ is finite of odd order. But it seems it was only important to prove first part of problem, that is every map from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is null-homotopic if m<n.

Comment: Note that if $\pi_1(M)$ is finite of odd order, then $H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is trivial and $M$ is orientable.  So actually that assumption automatically means you're in my second case.  It's a rather interesting coincidence that a totally different argument shows the result is still true in the non-orientable case.

Comment: Allright, it seems I have two more questions: How do you know that for non-orientable case $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is nontrivial? It seems that it uses Poincare duality, am I right?

Comment: And the second question: If $\pi_1(m)$ is finite of odd order then $0=H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}/2)=Hom(H_1(M),\mathbb{Z}/2)=Hom(\pi_1(M),\mathbb{Z}/2)$. Why the last equality is true?

Comment: For the latter: we do not need it in case of this problem, but this equality works sometimes. So my question remains the same ;)

Comment: For any manifold $M$, there is a homomorphism $\pi_1(M)\to\mathbb{Z}/2$ which sends a loop to $0$ if orientation is preserved along the loop and $1$ if orientation is reversed along the loop.  If $M$ is not orientable, this gives a nontrivial element of $H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}/2)$.  (This is also known as $w_1(TM)$, the first Stiefel-Whitney class of the tangent bundle of $M$.)

Comment: We have $Hom(H_1(M),\mathbb{Z}/2)=Hom(\pi_1(M),\mathbb{Z}/2)$ since by the Hurewicz theorem, $H_1(M)$ is the abelianization of $\pi_1(M)$.  So any homomorphism from $\pi_1(M)$ to an abelian group (such as $\mathbb{Z}/2$) factors uniquely through $H_1(M)$.  This is valid more generally for any path-connected space.